# SVG <image> tag not working in my .net application

Tags: .net, svg

I am new to SVG, I have a code in javascript that does some line drawings.  At the same time I have used some images.  When I run my codes in a simple HTML format, it works fine.  But when I integrated my codes in my .net project. The images in are not showing.  What seems to be the problem?

Here is the sample  tag code:

```
<image xlink:href='PersonalInfo2.png' x='10' y='10' height='10px' width='500px'/>
```

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Comment: got no run-time error, the image is simply not showing

Comment: href is with http . This might helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/24518578/5756149

Comment: What does it say in the Net tab of your browser dev tools?  It should help explain why it is not loading.  WHich browser are you using? Are you testing locally (ie. file://) or via a web server (http://)? etc etc.

Comment: Things to check:

* Is the image included in the project
* Is the image added to source control
* Have you added the `xlink` namespace to the svg tag
* Is the path to the image correct (relative to the route the page is displayed from) - check in F12 tools network tab for a 404 error